# Tomcat Unable to find CDI BeanManager

Tags: tomcat, jsf, cdi

I have the following exception, and search the last three days. Maybe one of you guys has an idea?
Actualy I want to get jsf-2 running with a bean, that get another bean injected.
They should have different scopes. One is actually only for a form and one holds the data for the whole session.

```
jakarta.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:463)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.performOneTimeELInitialization(ExpressionLanguage.java:183)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.getELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.dhbw.karlsruhe.webengineering</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>10.0.8</tomcat.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            <name>webapp</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and one of my Bean:

```
package Controller;

import Entity.TodoItem;
import Entity.TodoList;
import jakarta.faces.application.Application;
import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import jakarta.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;

import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AddOrEdit implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty("#{todoItem}")
    TodoItem item;
    @ManagedProperty("#{todoList}")
    TodoList list;

    public String test(){
        System.out.println("blub");
//        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
//        Application application = context.getApplication();
//        TodoList profileBean = application.evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{todoList}", TodoList.class);
//        TodoItem item = application.evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{todoItem}", TodoItem.class);
//        profileBean.addItem(item);
        this.list.addItem(item);
        System.out.println(this.list.getItems().size());
        return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public TodoItem getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(TodoItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public TodoList getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(TodoList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

faces-config.xml:

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding a context file `context.xml` into the `WEB-INF` Folder with this content:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager"
          auth="Container"
          type="jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
          factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```